# Fixed CSSGrid Navbar with Body overflowing

Tags: html, css, navbar, fixed

I have created a fixed Nav bar using CSSGrid but when scrolling, the Body scrolls over the navbar instead of underneath it. 
I assume it has something to do with the Z-index and position specified, but cannot quite figure it out.
Tried a few of the other options recommended here on Stack Overflow but with no success.

```
 <body class="container">
<div class="navigation">
  <img
    src="./img/test.svg"
    alt="Logo"
    class="navigation__logo"
  />
  <ul class="navigation__list-1">
    <li class="navigation__item">
      <a href="#" class="navigation__link">About Us</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navigation__item">
      <a href="#" class="navigation__link">Our Clients</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navigation__item">
      <a href="#" class="navigation__link">How we work</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navigation__item">
      <a href="#" class="navigation__link">Advantages</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navigation__item">
      <a href="#" class="navigation__link">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="navigation__list-2">
    <li class="navigation__registration">
      <a href="#" class="navigation__link">Register</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navigation__login">
      <a href="#" class="navigation__link">Login</a>
    </li>
    <!-- <li class="navigation__logout">Logout</li> -->
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="header">HEADER</div>
<main class="main">MAIN</main>
<footer class="footer">FOOTER</footer>
```

**CSS Styling (SCSS)**

```
body {
  font-family: $font-ak-reg;
  color: $color-primary;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 2.2rem;
  height: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 9rem repeat(2, minmax(5rem, min-content));
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  row-gap: 3rem;
}

.navigation {
  // margin: 2rem;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  // background-color: aqua;

  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20rem 1fr 65rem 1fr 20rem;
  box-shadow: 10px 3px 30px 0 rgba(74, 144, 226, 0.21);
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
```

Appreciate any assistance.

[image: Sample Issue Image]

[Link to Codepen](https://codepen.io/asdutoit/pen/dybjdWp)

Comment: try to write the code with saving on order. like the body should not be with grid.
And I see that the background-color a work solution :)

Comment: @Omer thanks!  I think you right.  It's probably better that I wrap all the child elements of the Body in a separate div, maybe Wrapper like "piyushjain" also proposed.

Answer (score 1):

Your z-index seems to be ok.

So, in css under `.navigation` css rule specify the color of the navbar.

Add to `.navigation` the following rule:

```
background: #ffff;
```

Comment: Wow, as simple as that.   It worked.   Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution.

html :-

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">HEADER</div>
  <main class="main">MAIN</main>
  <footer class="footer">FOOTER</footer>
</div>
```

css :-

```
.wrapper {
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 11;
}
```

Let me know if you have doubt.

Comment: Hi there, this solution also worked like a charm.  Thanks so much!